# Burst Mode Vs Fully Streaming XSLT

Tags: streaming, xslt-3.0

I have written an XSLT to transform a huge incoming XML file to JSON using burst mode streaming. I am new to XSLT and have heard that there is a better way of fully streaming XSLT code which is more efficient and faster then burst mode.

Can someone please help me understand -
1. What is the difference between burst mode vs Fully streaming ?
2. How can i convert below XSLT code to fully streaming to improve the perfomance?

Below is my burst mode XSLT code -

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT1109_CR_REV_Customer_Invoices_to_Connect" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <xsl:iterate select="wd:Report_Entry/copy-of()">
            <!--Define Running Totals for Statistics -->
            <xsl:param name="TotalHeaderCount" select="0"/>
            <xsl:param name="TotalLinesCount" select="0"/>
            <!--Write Statistics -->
            <xsl:on-completion>
                <xsl:text>{"Stats": </xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>{"Total Header Count": </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$TotalHeaderCount"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>"Total Lines Count": </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$TotalLinesCount"/>
                <xsl:text>}}</xsl:text>
            </xsl:on-completion>
            <!--Write Header Details -->
            <xsl:text>{"id": "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:id"/>
            <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>"revenue_stream": "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:revenue_stream"/>
            <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
            <!--Write Line Details -->
            <xsl:text>"lines": [  </xsl:text>
            <!-- Count the number of lines for an invoice -->
            <xsl:variable name="Linescount" select="wd:total_lines"/>
            <xsl:iterate select="wd:lines">
                <xsl:text>      {</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>"sequence": </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:sequence"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>"sales_item_id": "</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:sales_item_id"/>
                <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
            </xsl:iterate>
            <xsl:text>}]}&#10;</xsl:text>
            <!--Store Running Totals -->
            <xsl:next-iteration>
                <xsl:with-param name="TotalHeaderCount" select="$TotalHeaderCount + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="TotalLinesCount" select="$TotalLinesCount + $Linescount"/>                
            </xsl:next-iteration>
        </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the sample XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT1109_CR_REV_Customer_Invoices_to_Connect">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:id>CUSTOMER_INVOICE-6-1</wd:id>
        <wd:revenue_stream>TESTA</wd:revenue_stream>        
        <wd:total_lines>1</wd:total_lines>
        <wd:lines>
            <wd:sequence>ab</wd:sequence>
            <wd:sales_item_id>Administrative Cost</wd:sales_item_id>            
        </wd:lines>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:id>CUSTOMER_INVOICE-6-10</wd:id>
        <wd:revenue_stream>TESTB</wd:revenue_stream>        
        <wd:total_lines>1</wd:total_lines>
        <wd:lines>
            <wd:sequence>ab</wd:sequence>
            <wd:sales_item_id>Data - Web Access</wd:sales_item_id>
        </wd:lines>
    </wd:Report_Entry>  
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Comment: "there is a better way of fully streaming XSLT code which is more efficient and faster then burst mode": where is that said, any linkable article that claims that? For which implementation exactly? In general using `copy-of()` eases your task of selecting child content the way people are used to from XSLT 1 and 2 but can require more memory. But using more memory doesn't mean necessarily it is slower. So does your current approach perform poorly? In terms of memory consumption? Or in terms of speed? As for avoiding `copy-of()`, look into accumulators and, with JSON being the target, maps.

Comment: It would also help if you provide a short input sample and the corresponding JSON you want to create. Does the posted XSLT create a single top-level JSON object or a sequence of objects?

Comment: Martin, I have updated the above XSLT and added sample XML. Eventually I would need to transform XML with 60 fields and close to 50,000 Header and 10,000,000 lines. I have tested wit 80 Header and 50,000 lines and it took close to 4 minutes. I am not sure if i can 
extrapolate my final execution time looking at this. Therefore wanted to look at other options as well when
I read about fully streaming XSLT in my product community with not much detail though and could not find enough on-line as well.

Comment: Would really appreciate if you can share your experience about fully streaming vs burst mode and when should we use one over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of properties in the JSON doesn't matter then you could directly create XSLT/XPath 3 maps and arrays with `xsl:map/xsl:map-entry` (or the XPath 3.1 `map` constructor) and the Saxon specific extension element `saxon:array` (unfortunately the XSLT 3 language standard lacks an instruction to create an array). Furthermore most of your iteration parameters seem to be easily implemented as accumulators:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/INT1109_CR_REV_Customer_Invoices_to_Connect"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="adaptive" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" use-accumulators="#all" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="header-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Report_Entry" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:accumulator name="lines-count" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Report_Entry/total_lines/text()" select="$value + xs:integer(.)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:sequence
            select="map {
                     'Stats': map { 
                          'Total Header Count' : accumulator-after('header-count'),
                          'Total Lines Count' : accumulator-after('lines-count')
                        }
                    }"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry/id | Report_Entry/revenue_stream | lines/sequence | lines/sales_item_id">
        <xsl:map-entry key="local-name()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry/lines">
        <xsl:map-entry key="local-name()">
            <saxon:array>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </saxon:array>
        </xsl:map-entry>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The example uses output method adaptive as your current sample doesn't create a single JSON object and I have simply tried to create the same output as your current code; the JSON output method would need a single map or array as the main sequence result.

Code works with streaming and Saxon EE 9.9.1.1 in oXygen, unfortunately 9.8 doesn't consider the code streamable.

As for general rules, there are limits as to what you can achieve with accumulators and template matching when streaming; as you can see, the accumulator to sum up the values from the `total_lines` elements needs to match on the text child to not consume the element in the accumulator (Saxon has another extension of capturing accumulators to ease such tasks however).

So far I would rather say it is more important to find a way to get around the streamability analysis and to have the streamable code return the right and same result as the non-streamable code; for instance, while experimenting with an approach to generate JSON with streaming using two transformation steps where some sample data similar to yours is the input, the XML representation for JSON the result of the first transformation and the JSON supposed to be the result of using `xml-to-json` on the first step's result I ran into a Saxon bug https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4215.

With streaming, it seems there is not enough test coverage or implementation maturity to be able to combine features reliably in a complex and scalable way, partly due to a complex spec, partly due to the limited use of that stuff by the XSLT community.

So if you find a working way for a particular problem to use streaming to keep memory consumption lower or manageable compared to the normal XSLT 2/3 tree based processing then you can of course experiment with changes to improve performance but it is easy to break things.

One general observation is that streaming allows you to access all attributes of the currently processed/matched element but not its children, therefore it can help immensely to insert a processing steps that transforms elements into attributes if you have a simple child element structure. That way you can then often avoid any `copy-of()`. But of course you need a way to combine two stylesheets which Saxon allows with its API but doing it requires writing Java or .NET code.